# Spark MLlib / K-Means intuition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm very new to machine learning algorithms and Spark. I'm follow the
Twitter Streaming Language Classifier found here:

http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/twitter_classifier/README.html

Specifically this code:

http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/ExamineAndTrain.scala

Except I'm trying to run it in batch mode on some tweets it pulls out
of Cassandra, in this case 200 total tweets.

As the example shows, I am using this object for "vectorizing" a set of tweets:

```
object Utils{
  val numFeatures = 1000
  val tf = new HashingTF(numFeatures)

  /**
   * Create feature vectors by turning each tweet into bigrams of
   * characters (an n-gram model) and then hashing those to a
   * length-1000 feature vector that we can pass to MLlib.
   * This is a common way to decrease the number of features in a
   * model while still getting excellent accuracy (otherwise every
   * pair of Unicode characters would potentially be a feature).
   */
  def featurize(s: String): Vector = {
    tf.transform(s.sliding(2).toSeq)
  }
}
```

Here is my code which is modified from ExaminAndTrain.scala:

```
 val noSets = rawTweets.map(set => set.mkString("\n"))

val vectors = noSets.map(Utils.featurize).cache()
vectors.count()

val numClusters = 5
val numIterations = 30

val model = KMeans.train(vectors, numClusters, numIterations)

  for (i <- 0 until numClusters) {
    println(s"\nCLUSTER $i")
    noSets.foreach {
        t => if (model.predict(Utils.featurize(t)) == 1) {
          println(t)
        }
      }
    }
```

This code runs and each Cluster prints "Cluster 0" "Cluster 1" etc
with nothing printing beneath. If i flip

```
models.predict(Utils.featurize(t)) == 1
```

to

```
models.predict(Utils.featurize(t)) == 0
```

the same thing happens except every tweet is printed beneath every cluster.

Here is what I intuitively think is happening (please correct my
thinking if its wrong): This code turns each tweet into a vector,
randomly picks some clusters, then runs kmeans to group the tweets (at
a really high level, the clusters, i assume, would be common
"topics"). As such, when it checks each tweet to see if models.predict
== 1, different sets of tweets should appear under each cluster (and
because its checking the training set against itself, every tweet
should be in a cluster). Why isn't it doing this? Either my
understanding of what kmeans does is wrong, my training set is too
small or I'm missing a step.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all KMeans is a clustering algorithm and as such unsupervised. So there is no "checking of the training set against itself" (well okay you can do it manually ;).

Your understanding is quite good actually, just that you miss the point that model.predict(Utils.featurize(t)) gives you the cluster that t belongs as assigned by KMeans. I think you want to check

`models.predict(Utils.featurize(t)) == i`

in your code since i iterates through all cluster labels.

Also a small remark: The feature vector is created on a 2-gram model of **characters** of the tweets. This intermediate step is important ;)

2-gram (for words) means: "A bear shouts at a bear" => {(A, bear), (bear, shouts), (shouts, at), (at, a), (a bear)} i.e. "a bear" is counted twice. Chars would be (A,[space]), ([space], b), (b, e) and so on.

Comment: it's `bigrams of characters` so it should be `{("A ", " b", "be" ...}`.

Comment: Thank you for this response uberwatch. I made that change and it printed the 5 clusters, except cluster 0 had all the tweets under it while the remaining clusters had none which I assume means all the tweets are getting assigned to cluster 0.  Is this because the dataset is too small? (I think in the example provided by databricks they train the kmeans model on something like 12 million tweets while I'm only using 200). Or should numClusters/numIterations be tweaked?

Comment: Or is it because it's classifying the tweets based on language (as it is in the databricks example)? Perhaps they all get assigned to cluster 0 because that, at a high level, is the "english" cluster. Is this because it's looking at bigrams of characters? Would looking at bigrams of words be more akin to looking at "topics" within the tweets? If so, how would to modify Utils to have it create bigrams of words instead of characters?

Comment: Nevermind on the last question, I see HashingTF.transform accepts the tweet string and you can manipulate it using common string methods. Final question, is there a way to see what points were chosen by the clusters? Could i see their vector then go from the vector back to the word(s) it corresponds to?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but no. Hashing is supposed to be non-invertible.