# K-Means clustering is biased to one center

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have a corpus of wiki pages (baseball, hockey, music, football) which I'm running through `tfidf` and then through `kmeans`. After a couple issues to start (you can see my previous questions), I'm finally getting a `KMeansModel`...but when I try to `predict`, I keep getting the same center. Is this because of the small dataset, or because I'm comparing a multi-word document against a smaller amount of words(1-20) query? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong? See the below code:

```
//Preprocessing of data includes splitting into words 
//and removing words with only 1 or 2 characters
val corpus: RDD[Seq[String]]
val hashingTF = new HashingTF(100000)
val tf = hashingTF.transform(corpus)
val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf = idf.transform(tf).cache
val kMeansModel = KMeans.train(tfidf, 3, 10)

val queryTf = hashingTF.transform(List("music"))
val queryTfidf = idf.transform(queryTf)
kMeansModel.predict(queryTfidf) //Always the same, no matter the term supplied
```

This question seems somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929704/spark-mllib-k-means-intuition)

Answer (score 3):

More a checklist than an answer:

1. A single word query or a very short sentence is probably not a good choice especially when combined with a large feature vector. I would start with significant fragments of the documents from the corpus

   Manually check similarity between query an each cluster. Is it even remotely similar to each cluster?

   ```scala
   import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV, SparseVector => BSV, Vector => BV}
   import breeze.linalg.functions.cosineDistance
   import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, SparseVector, DenseVector}

   def toBreeze(v: Vector): BV[Double] = v match {
     case DenseVector(values) => new BDV[Double](values)
     case SparseVector(size, indices, values) => {
       new BSV[Double](indices, values, size)
     }
   }

   val centers =  kMeansModel.clusterCenters.map(toBreeze(_))
   val query = toBreeze(queryTfidf)
   centers.map(c => cosineDistance(query, c))
   ```
2. Does K-Means converge? Depending on a dataset and initial centroids ten or twenty iterations can be not enough. Try to increase this number to one thousand or so and see if the problem persist.
3. Is your corpus diverse enough to form meaningful clusters? Try to find centroids for each document in you corpus. Do you get a relatively uniform distribution or almost all documents are assigned to a single cluster.

   Perform visual inspection. Take your `tfidf` RDD convert to a matrix, apply PCA, plot, color by cluster and see if you get a meaningful results.

   Plot centroids as well and check if these cover possible cluster. If not check convergence once again.

   You can also check similarities between centroids:

   ```scala
   (0 until centers.size)
     .toList
     .flatMap(i => ((i + 1) until centers.size)
     .map(j => (i, j, 1 - cosineDistance(centers(i), centers(j)))))
   ```
4. Is your pre-processing thorough enough? Simple removal of the short words most likely won't suffice. I would at lest extend it using with stopwords removal. Some stemming wouldn't hurt too.
5. K-Means results depend on the initial centroids. Try running an algorithm multiple times an see if problem persists.
6. Try more sophisticated algorithm like LDA

Comment: Thanks! Ill try these suggestions tonight.